# Put array elements into hidden input

Tags: php, arrays

my head is starting to explode :(

I am trying to put index of array as a name of input and value of array as value of input. I simply need it to do this way :)

array named **$arrAddItems** which I go through is:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [479]=>
    string(2) "83"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [345]=>
    string(3) "348"
  }
}
```

I need this output when form is submitted:

```
 [345]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "348"
  }

 [479]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "83"
  }
```

My code to do that is:

```
foreach($arrAddItems as $addItem) { echo key($addItem);?>
    <input type="hidden" name="<?=key($addItem);?>[]" value="<?=$addItem;?>">
<?php
}
?>
```

I know it is something obvious, but I cannot see it :(

Thx for help.
martin

Answer (score 1):

try to

```
foreach($arrAddItems as $key => $value){
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution - this is the right code:

```
foreach($arrAddItems as $addItem) { ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="<?=key($addItem);?>[]" value="<?=$addItem[key($addItem)];?>">
<?php
}
?>
```